# Finding the value of $(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2})^{2015} - (\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2})^{2015}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I wish to find the value of $(\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2})^{2015} - (\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2})^{2015}$

Since $2015 = 5(13)(31)$, I think I should find the values of $(\frac{1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2})^{5}$ and then count by 5 up to $2015$ to see what the actual root is. Do the same for the other fraction.

So, $\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ has a modulus of $1$ and an argument of $\frac{\pi}{3}$. Then, 
$(\frac{1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2})^{5} = \cos(\frac{\pi}{15} + \frac{2k\pi}{5}) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{15} + \frac{2k\pi}{5})$ for $k = 0,1,2,3,4$.

Then,

$z_0 = \cos(\frac{\pi}{15})+ i\sin(\frac{\pi}{15})$

$z_1 = \cos(\frac{\pi}{15} + 2\pi) + i\sin(\frac{\pi}{15} + 2\pi)$

$\vdots$

Is there a better way to solve this exercise? Converting all five roots will be a tedious chore since we will have to apply trig summation identites.

Comment: Apply De Moivre's Theorem, or use exponential form?

Comment: Where did the division by 5 come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:*  $\left(\dfrac{1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{3}=-1$

Comment: Wouldn't it be more simple to calculate what the fifth root of $(\frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2})^5$? Since $5$ divides $2015$, the value at power $2015$ will be the same as the value at the power of $5$. Do that for both quantities and subtract.

Comment: @Koli, I don't think so.

Comment: Hm, well your information is useful because $\left ( \frac{1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right )$ is easier to find than higher powers of complex numbers. So, $\left (\frac{1+i\sqrt{3})}{2} \right )^2 = -\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Since $2015 \mod{3} $ is $2$, then $\left ( \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right )^{2015} = -\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: And $\left ( \frac{1 - i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right )^2 = -\frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Then we have $\left ( \frac{1 - i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right )^{2015} = -\frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $.  There, our answer is $-\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: Do you agree with my calculation?

Comment: @Koli, it seems fine. I suggest you add your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we have $$\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^{2015}-\left(\frac{1-i\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^{2015}$$ $$=\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^{2015}-\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\right)^{2015}$$
$$=\left(\cos \frac{\pi}{3}+i\sin \frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{2015}-\left(\cos \frac{\pi}{3}-i\sin \frac{\pi}{3}\right)^{2015} $$
$$=\left(\cos \frac{2015\pi}{3}+i\sin \frac{2015\pi}{3}\right)-\left(\cos \frac{2015\pi}{3}-i\sin \frac{2015\pi}{3}\right)$$
$$=2i\sin \left(\frac{2015\pi}{3}\right)=2i\sin\left( 672\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$
$$=2i\sin\left( 2(336)\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=-2i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$$$=-2i\times \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}=\color{red}{-i\sqrt 3}$$